# Flask output is broken and not complete

Tags: python, flask

When I open a certain page in my app, the output returns the complete result but for some other pages (which is exactly the same from a format perspective) the output result gets cut off (i.e., it doesn't show me the complete page. Also, in some cases, it doesn't even show the output result.

----- the .py Code ------

```
class SHCDCConfig:
    def __init__(self, vlanid, description, vrf, ip, mask):
        self.vlanid = vlanid
        self.description = description
        self.vrf = vrf
        self.ip = ip
        self.mask = mask

    def vxlan_config(self):
        return f"""
            vlan {self.vlanid}
             name {self.description}
             vn-segment 12{self.vlanid}
             exit\n
            interface vlan {self.vlanid}
             vrf member {self.vrf}
             description {self.description}
             ip address {self.ip} {self.mask}
             fabric forwarding mode anycast-gateway
             no ip redirects
             no shut
             exit\n
             interface nve1 
              member vni 12{self.vlanid}  
              multisite ingress-replication
              suppress-arp
              ingress-replication protocol bgp
             exit\n
             exit\n
            evpn
             vni 12{self.vlanid} l2
                rd auto
                route-target import auto
                route-target export auto
                exit\n
            """
```

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from SHCConfigFile import DistroConfig, SHCDCConfig, AccessSwitch
from flask import send_file


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/vxlan_config', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def vxlan_config():
    import os

    vxlan_config_file = open("/Users/ahmad/ShcConfigs/vxlan_config.txt", "w")
    if request.method == "POST":
        vlanid = request.form["vlanid"]
        description = request.form["description"]
        vrf = request.form["vrf"]
        ip = request.form["ip"]
        mask = request.form["mask"]
        vxlan_conf = SHCDCConfig(vlanid, description, vrf, ip, mask)
        vxlan_config_file.write(vxlan_conf.vxlan_config())
        return send_file("/Users/ahmad/ShcConfigs/vxlan_config.txt", attachment_filename='vxlan_config')
    return render_template('vxlan_config.html')
```

------- the html template ----------

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<html>
            <body>
                    <p><h3>Enter the Values Below:</h3></p>
                    <form method="post" action="/vxlan_config">
                        <p>VLAN ID: <input name="vlanid" placeholder=3400></p>
                        <p>VLAN Description: <input name="description" placeholder=CitrixVLAN></p>
                        <p>VRF Name: <input name="vrf" placeholder=GRN200></p>
                        <p>SVI IP Address: <input name="ip" placeholder=10.248.10.1></p>
                        <p>VLAN Subnet Mask: <input name="mask" placeholder=255.255.255.0></p>
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Generate Config" /></p>
                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to show the code that displays the output.

Comment: return send_file("/Users/ahmad/ShcConfigs/vxlan_config.txt", attachment_filename='vxlan_config')

Comment: the above shows the output

Comment: Where? I see the `<form>` code, but that's it

Comment: so my understanding is that when i open a file and write to that file, then i will "send_file" that file and that will return the output in once user click generate. is my understanding wrong? or do i have a fundamental issue here?

Comment: this is all under the "def vxlan_config()"

Comment: You're going to have to show the code for `SHCDCConfig()`.  Also, put quotes around your placeholder strings.  `placeholder=Citrix VLAN` is invalid

Comment: i will update the question with that code, i have fixed the placeholder too, thanks for looking in details :)

Comment: @GAEfan, keep in mind that 50% of the time the whole thing works. i just dont know why

Comment: See update to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the specs for `send_file()`:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file

1. The file path should be relative to the root of your app, not relative to your computer's logged-in user.
2. `attachment_filename` should be left off, or else it should have the `.txt` extension, so the mimetype is correct
3. Since your app is overwriting the same file continuously, you should probably set the `cache_timeout` to a small value.  Else, some repeat users might see an older version.
4. Put quotes around your placeholder strings. `placeholder=Citrix VLAN` is invalid

**UPDATE:**

You may be having a buffer issue.  Try:

```
import os
vxlan_config_file.write(vxlan_conf.vxlan_config())
  
vxlan_config_file.flush() 
  
os.fsync(vxlan_config_file.fileno()) 
 
vxlan_config_file.close()
```